# How do I assign a context path prefix to multiple Spring Boot classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bunch of resources in my Spring Boot project. Instead of giving them fully static paths, I'd prefer to make the prefixes (i.e. /attributes/, /entitites/ etc.) configurable. Previously, I used the servlet.context-path settings, but I'd like to have a different path per package in my project and different path for static resources...

I.e. all beans from package Entities being mapped to a context with a prefix /{servlet.context-path}/entities/{RequestMapping}, beans from my package attributes to /{servlet.context-path}/attributes/{RequestMapping} without having to specify a static prefix, such as /attributes/static/list in every single bean.

Comment: What do you mean by path ? is it the endpoint name ?

Comment: Yeah, Context-Path...

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and I have resolve with this Configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class FeaturesRestConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.addPathPrefix(
        "apiPackage1",
        HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class)
            .and(
                HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage(
                    "com.projects.api.package1")));
  }
}
```

All java class with RestController annotation automatically have *apiPackage1* prefixed in url.

tested on a Spring Boot 2.2 application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have prefixed RequestMapping per package and to don't repeat your slef you can create an abstract controller per package; for example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entities", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE})
public abstract class EntitiesAbstractController {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/attributes", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE})
public abstract class AttributesAbstractController {
}
```

And then in you controllers you'll have :

```
@RestController
public class ChildController extends EntitiesAbstractController{
   @GetMapping(value="/PATH_SUFFIX_HERE")
   //method here
}
```

So beside your `servlet.context-path`, you will have endpoints that looks like this :

```
/{servlet.context-path}/entities/PATH_SUFFIX_HERE
/{servlet.context-path}/attributes/PATH_SUFFIX_HERE
```

Comment: Is there a way to drill down further though? I have multiple controllers per package and would like to group those uder a common prefix.

Comment: Gotcha. So the classes are being inspected recursively, so parent classes end up being the prefix for all children?

Comment: I don't think so ! I think that you can have only one level of inheritance ! but you can try it and tell us the result that you'll get

Comment: It seems that while it's possible to use a parent class for the @RequestMapping annotation, you can't have an additional one for a subpath on the child class, only on the individual methods. Which kind of defeats the purpose of a common prefix.